# Crashes/ UncaughtExceptions are not tracked in Google analytics in Titanium

Tags: google-analytics, titanium

I have integrated the Google analytics module downloaded from market place and was able to track events, screens, user timings etc.

But crashes are not tracked in Google analytics. What I have observed is Titanium itself handles the Application crash and showing run-time exception in a red screen in Development mode.  So I thought this might be the reason for the crashes not being tracked in Google analytics. So I have uploaded a sample application to play store and tested the application for crashes in production mode (I have included the code for crash when the button is selected).

But I haven't observe any crash but the code execution after the crash  statement stopped and the crash was not tracked in Google analytics.

I have included the following code to track the crashes in the application in titanium

```
GA.trackUncaughtExceptions = true;
```

Please suggest.

Comment: usually the module comes with support email. I would suggest trying to contact the module developer for technical help. he might have a bug in his module or he could assist you better. next time also publish the name + link to the module you used.

Comment: I have downloaded the module from the following link https://marketplace.appcelerator.com/apps/5081#!overview                                  . I have also posted a question in the market place and also mailed to the module developer(heardtheword@gmail.com) but no reply.